# psshutdown fails unless run from admin cmd prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, psexec, reboot

Ok here's an interesting problem I've run into. I'm attempting to reboot some computers remotely using psshutdown and getting access denied errors unless I run the cmd from a cmd prompt that was run as admin. I myself am an admin on my machine as well as on the remote computer so my credentials should work just fine.

Example code:

```
psshutdown /accepteula \\COMPUTER.DOMAIN.COM -u DOMAIN\USER -p Password -r -t 0
```

Example output:

```
Could not start PsShutdown service on COMPUTER.DOMAIN.COM:
Access is denied.
```

However when run from admin cmd window:

```
COMPUTER.DOMAIN.COM is scheduled to reboot in 00:00:00.
```

As kludge-y as it seems, is it possible to use psexec to run psshutdown as an elevated user?

Answer (score 0):

After running around in circles with this I ended up using:

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME "shutdown -m \\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -r -f -t 0"
```

Which isn't ideal but got the job done.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, try this. It will open an external window where you can remotely shutdown computers on your network:

```
    shutdown -i
```

You can type this straight into the CMD window without needing to create a .bat file.
Hope this helps!